# Is the set of Valuation Functions finite?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've been learning about interpretation functions and valuation functions. Intuitively, it seems as though there are an infinite number of Interpretation Functions, which I will denote as $I_n$.

i.e. given the set of all possible atomic well-formed formulas (which is presumably infinite), there must be a similarly infinite number of $I_n$...this belief is motivated by the idea that if I have an infinite list of atomic well-formed formulas (**wffs**), then I have a correspondingly infinite way of assigning them Truth/False values...each assignment strategy results from one specific $I_n$

However, for Valuation Functions, it seems as though I only have 6, which are limited to the 6 basic complex **wffs**.

1. the valuation function that operates on a propositional letter
2. the valuation function that operates on a negated proposition
3. the valuation function that operates on a conjunction proposition
4. the valuation function that operates on a disjunction proposition
5. the valuation function that operates on a conditional proposition
6. the valuation function that operates on a biconditional proposition

Does this mean that the set of valuation functions is effectively finite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A valuation function maps formulas to truth values. There is not a different valuation function for disjuctions vs. propositional letters. The valuation function is defined as an extension of a truth assignment for propositional letters, by induction on formula structure and the standard truth tables.

Since each valuation function is determined by a truth assignment on propositional letters, there are as many valuation functions as there are truth assignments on propositional letters. And this depends how many propositional letters there are: if there are $n$, then there are $2^n$ truth assignments.

So if there are infinitely many propositional letters, then there are infinitely many truth assignments. For example, if there are a countably infinite number of propositional letters (which is usually the case), then there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ (cardinality of the reals) many truth assignments, and hence that many valuation functions.

Comment: Hmmm, if this is the case, then how does the valuation function take into consideration the different truth-function operators? I would have thought that there was one valuation function for each truth-function operator (because the mappings are unique to the specific truth-function operator in question). i.e. if I have two propositional letters, one of which is false and one of which is true, then the valuation function surely maps “AND” to a different value than “OR”

Comment: It is defined recursively: $v(A\land B) = v(A)\cdot v(B)$ and $v(\lnot A)=-v(A)$ where $-$ and $\cdot$ are the truth table functions ($\cdot$ can be viewed as the same as ordinary multiplication on $\{0,1\}$ and $-$ takes $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $0$). At the bottom level of the recursion (the propositional letters) there is just some arbitrary function taking the letters to $\{0,1\}.$

Comment: " if I have two propositional letters, one of which is false and one of which is true, 
 then the valuation function surely maps “AND” to a different value than “OR” "... The choice of valuation function (really the underlying truth assignment) is what determines, that (for instance) letter $p$ is true and $q$ is false. If we choose a truth assignment $v$ such that $v(p)=1$ and $v(q)=0,$ then by the recursive definition, this extends to a valuation function that obeys $v(p\land q)=0$ and $v(p\lor q) = 1.$

Comment: @S.Cramer It's worth noting that we can also define a valuation as simply a map $\nu$ from the set of propositional atoms to $\{$True, False$\}$; *from this* we then define a larger map $\hat{\nu}$ from the set of all propositional formulas to $\{$True, False$\}$ by recursion "with $\nu$ as the base case" using rules like "if $\hat{\nu}(\varphi)$ and $\hat{\nu}(\psi)$ are each True, then $\hat{\nu}(\varphi\wedge\psi)$ is True."

Comment: In either interpretation, the thing that is finite isn't the set of all valuations - rather, it's the set of **recursive clauses** in the definition of what it means to be a "valuation" (or in the definition of how $\hat{\nu}$ is built up from $\nu$).